How to use an @State property from a Sendable Closure in SwiftUI?
Here, hasComplexWave is a Boolean @State on a SwiftUI View. Here’s the code that uses it:
view.visualEffect { [hasComplexWave] content, proxy in
    content.distortionEffect(
        ShaderLibrary.complexWave(
            .float(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow),
            .float2(proxy.size),
            .float(0.5),
            .float(8),
            .float(10)
        ),
        maxSampleOffset: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100),
        isEnabled: hasComplexWave
    )
}

The problem is, this gives me a warning in swift 5 and an error in swift 6, as follows:

Main actor-isolated property 'hasComplexWave' can not be referenced from a Sendable closure; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

What is the very best way to fix this error?

You can add a “capture list” to the closure to avoid referencing the actor-isolated property in the closure.
Thus, replace …
view.visualEffect { content, proxy in … }

… with:
view.visualEffect { [hasComplexWave] content, proxy in … }

See Capture Lists and Capturing Values from The Swift Programming Language.

Thanks for the edit, Rob! And this compiled without warning or error. VERY nice.

I see. So the warning is using 'reference' meaning strong reference, yes? The warning is literal.

See Closures, which says “Closures can capture and store references to any constants and variables from the context in which they’re defined. This is known as closing over those constants and variables. Swift handles all of the memory management of capturing for you.” Do not conflate this with the weak/strong references to class objects.
